# "Makes someone and __ do something" — I or me?

Tags: pronouns

I have a sentence "So thoughtful and just makes Mrs. Smith and I miss them even more!"

Is this grammatically correct? I'm in doubt because I'm not certain whether "Mrs. Smith and I" is a compound subject or a compound object. I would say "Mrs. Smith and I miss them even more" (without the passive piece in the front), but at the same moment I'd say "It makes me miss them even more".

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give a bit more context please?

Comment: Not really, I'm pretty sure that's all the context there is. Here's another sentence immediately before this one: "Thank you so much for all the lovely messages and signs from the ##### yesterday! So thoughtful and just makes Mrs. Smith and I miss them even more!"

Comment: As you say, it's _makes me miss them_ so it's _makes Mrs. Smith and me miss them_. I was always taught that you use the form that would be correct if the other person were not mentioned.